# Como usar o for pra comparar um index específico?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Na função `bonAppetit`, eu quero pegar apenas o índice `k` (no caso, k=1 e o valor é 10), e ver se esse numero é menor ou igual a `b`.

Só que o meu programa está rodando a lista inteira.

```
def bonAppetit(bill, k, b):
    n = len(bill)

    for k in range(n):
        if bill[k] >= b:
            print('Bon Appetit')
    del(bill[k])
    x = sum(bill)
    if x / 2 < b:
        y = (b - (x / 2))
        print(f'{y:.0f}')
print(bonAppetit([3, 10, 2, 9], 1, 7))
```

***output desejado:***

```
Bon Appetit
```

***output que estou tendo:***

```
Bon Appetit
Bon Appetit
```

Answer (score 3):

Se você só quer um índice específico em vez da lista inteira, então acesse o elemento diretamente em vez de fazer um `for`:

```
def bonAppetit(bill, k, b):
    if bill[k] >= b: # <-- **AQUI** - não precisa de for, acesse o índice diretamente
        print('Bon Appetit')
    del(bill[k])
    x = sum(bill)
    if x / 2 < b:
        y = (b - (x / 2))
        print(f'{y:.0f}')

bonAppetit([3, 10, 2, 9], 1, 7)
```

Também retirei a variável `n` que agora ficou sem uso, e ao chamar a função retirei o `print`, pois a função não retorna nenhum valor, então não há o que imprimir.